# Postgresql pg_dump and pg restore not restoring the whole data of a database

Tags: postgresql, psql, pythonanywhere, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to restore a database from server using following to backup :

```
pg_dump --host=HOSTNAME --port=PORT --username=super --format=c --file=data.dump mydb
```

and this command to restore

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d test_db < datad.dump --no-privileges --no-owner
```

It's restoring the database's some part and data stored in test_db before also exits they don't get wiped.

EDIT: 
These are the errors which get while pg_restore:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3152; 2606 24665 FK CONSTRAINT django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_accounts_user_id myadminuser
>   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_accounts_user_id" for relation "django_admin_log" already exists
>       Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY django_admin_log
>       ADD CONSTRAINT django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_accounts_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES accounts_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
>
> WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 177

Comment: Your description of events is not accurate. The "custom" format would just produce an error message if you tried to feed it to psql. If you want useful help it is vital to provide accurate information.

Comment: I update the question please have  a look

Comment: It seems you are restoring into a database that already contains tables, constraints (and possibly data as well). What is the exact `pg_restore` command you used? You might be looking for the `--clean` option to drop existing tables before restoring them.

Comment: I have stated  the command in question, and i am not using --clean and yes there some data in db in which i am restoring. So cleaning the db will solve the problem??